# Linux Apache CGI can't open lib when visiting the website

Tags: c++, linux, apache, web, unixodbc

I'm using unixODBC and Apache CGI to build a database website on Linux. The following problems occurred when I tested the query of the database.

```
Connect Error
[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so' : file not found (0)
```

The above information appears on another computer on which I tried to access the website using Windows.

```
http://serverIP/cgi-bin/website.cgi?first=1
```

Strangely, when I run this CGI file directly on the Linux server, it executes normally. That is, successfully connect to the database and query the output results. The successful connection of `isql` also proves that it can connect to the database.

Equivalent to the following

```
root@VM-4-11-ubuntu:~# /var/www/cgi-bin/website.cgi
Content-type:text/html

<html>
  <head>
    <title>test button</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Connected!</p>
    <p>SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = 1;<p>
    <p>id = 1 name = Tom</p>
  </body>
</html>
// -----
root@VM-4-11-ubuntu:~# curl http://localhost/cgi-bin/website.cgi
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test button</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Connect Error</p>
    <p>[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so' : file not found (0)</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The following is the code to output the error message

```
// In DataBase's constructor
// ...
  V_OD_erg = SQLConnect(V_OD_hdbc, dataSource, SQL_NTS,
                        usrName, SQL_NTS, password, SQL_NTS);
  if ((V_OD_erg != SQL_SUCCESS) && (V_OD_erg != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)) {
    noErr = false;
    printf("<p>Connect Error</p>\n");
    showDBCErr(V_OD_erg);
  }
// ...
void DataBase::showDBCErr(SQLRETURN retCode) {
  HandleDiagnosticRecord(V_OD_hdbc, SQL_HANDLE_DBC, retCode);
}
// ...
void DataBase::HandleDiagnosticRecord(SQLHANDLE hHandle, SQLSMALLINT hType,
                                      RETCODE RetCode) {
  SQLSMALLINT iRec = 0;
  SQLINTEGER iError;
  SQLCHAR wszMessage[1000];
  SQLCHAR wszState[SQL_SQLSTATE_SIZE + 1];

  if (RetCode == SQL_INVALID_HANDLE) {
    printf("<p>Invalid handle!</p>");
    return;
  }

  while (SQLGetDiagRec(hType, hHandle, ++iRec, wszState, &iError, wszMessage,
                       (SQLSMALLINT)(sizeof(wszMessage) / sizeof(SQLCHAR)),
                       (SQLSMALLINT*)NULL) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
    // Hide data truncated..
    if (strcmp((const char*)wszState, "01004")) {
      printf("<p>[%5.5s] %s (%d)</p>", wszState, wszMessage, iError);
    }
  }
}
```

```
// in /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC]
Trace=Yes
TraceFile=~/unixODBCLog/odbctrace.log

[GaussMPP]
Driver64=/usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so
setup=/usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so

// in ~/.bashrc
# ...
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export ODBCSYSINI=/usr/local/etc
export ODBCINI=/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
```

```
root@VM-4-11-ubuntu:~# odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7pre
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem. I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: I assume that the file `/usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so` actually exists on the server system?

Comment: Do the permissions on `/usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so` and its parent directories allow Apache to execute it?

Comment: ```/usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so``` does exist. Otherwise, I cannot connect to the database using ```isql```.

Comment: Then refer to the comment by @AlanBirtles. Do the user that runs Apache have access to that file and all parent directories? Generally don't use the `root` user for any kind of development, that can give you the false impression that things works (besides the security implications). Always test as the actual user that's supposed to run the program.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @Some programmer dude @Alan Birtles. I know little about authority. Should I try ```chmod 755 /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so``` ?

Comment: yes, those are appropriate permissions, make sure the parent directories have the same permissions too

Comment: ```drwxr-xr-x usr/  drwxr-xr-x local/  -rwxr-xr-x psqlodbcw.so*``` I set them like this, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is `mod_chroot` enabled in Apache or is Apache otherwise configured to run in  a chroot environment?

Comment: Is there any systemd configuration for Apache on your system?  If so, it would probably be in `/etc/systemd/system/apache2.service.d/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, guys, I've solved this problem. Like Some programmer dude said, "Generally don't use the root user for any kind of development, that can give you the false impression that things works ". When I use `tar` as `ubuntu` (not `root`), system shows the same error "file not found". Then I realize that the ODBC library installed as `root` may not be available to ordinary users. So I reinstall as `ubuntu`. It works!

Thanks, @Some programmer dude, @Alan Birtles, @Stephen Ostermiller